# Create a mask animation with CSS ans Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to redo this animation found on this [site](https://kozowood.com/en) (the animation is: click on "Let me in" then scroll down the equivalent of a screen and you have
title: "Wood houses make for sustainable homes.
Let's unpack the artistry behind them" and a round centered in width with a "K" logo. )
this circle with the central logo is a kind of mask/hole which, when scrolled, reveals the content.

I managed to redo part of the concept on my [codepen])https://codepen.io/jipe974/pen/gOEyyae)

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  // Créer le conteneur pour le masque
  var mask = document.createElement('div');
  mask.id = 'mask';
  // Insérer le masque dans le document
  var maskcontainer = document.querySelector(".container.fullscreen2");
  maskcontainer.appendChild(mask);

  window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    var scrollPercentage =
      (document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) /
      (document.documentElement.scrollHeight -
        document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    var newSize = 1500 * (1 + scrollPercentage);
    newSize = Math.min(newSize, 3000); // Limiter la taille maximale à 3000px

    // Vérifier si l'élément avec l'ID "mask" existe
    var maskElement = document.getElementById("mask");
    if (maskElement) {
      // Mettre à jour la taille du masque
      maskElement.style.width = newSize + "px";
      maskElement.style.height = newSize + "px";

      // Vérifier si le masque a atteint une certaine taille
      if (newSize >= 2500) {
        // Supprimer le masque
        maskElement.remove();
        // Activer le défilement du contenu
        document.querySelector(".content").style.overflow = "auto";
      } else {
        // Désactiver le défilement du contenu
        document.querySelector(".content").style.overflow = "hidden";
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container.fullscreen2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2000px; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
#mask {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 10000px solid red; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 3;
    transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container fullscreen2">
  <div class="content"> 
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent bibendum, lorem vel tincidunt imperdiet, nibh elit laoreet felis, a bibendum nisl tortor non orci. Donec pretium fermentum felis, quis aliquet est rutrum ut. Integer quis masssda ut lacus viverra pharetra in eu lacus. Aliquam tempus odio adipiscing diam pellentesque rhoncus. Curabitur a bibendum est. Mauris vehicula cursus risus id luctus. Curabitur accumsan venenatis nibh, non egestas ipsum vulputate ac. Vivamus consectetur dolor sit amet enim aliquet eu scelerisque ipsum hendrerit. Donec lobortis suscipit vestibulum. Nullam luctus pellentesque risus in ullamcorper. Nam neque nunc, mattis vitae ornare ut, feugiat a erat. Ut tempus iaculis augue vel pellentesque.</p>

<p>Vestibulum nunc massa, gravida quis porta nec, feugiat id metus. Nunc ac arcu odolor, quis vestibulum leo. Cras viverra mollis ipsum, non rhoncus lectus aliquam et. Morbi faucibus purus sit amet lacus aliquet elementum. Donec sit amet posuere enim. Cras in eros id tortor fringilla ultricies. Mauris faucibus ullamcorper velit, pulvinar varius odio eleifend eu. Quisque id odio metus. Morbi adipiscing ultricies posuere. Pellentesque elementum porttitor eros in molestie. Maecenas ut leo quis nisi tempor tincidunt.</p>

<p>Donec nunc ligula, vulputate quis mollis eu, interdum quis libero. Donec nulla ante, facilisis sit amet vulputate at, tincidunt a velit. Maecenas vestibulum, nulla sed tincidunt viverra, lorem turpis aliquam urna, ut pretium orci purus consequat augue. Etiam a enim orci, vitae pulvinar odio. In elit urna, tincidunt a pellentesque et, scelerisque at nibh. Sed nec est sapien. Aliquam ullamcorper eros eu quam ultrices vel faucibus eros interdum. Etiam mattis eleifend sapien, eu iaculis massa feugiat sed. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus facilisis ultricies eros, a pretium purus mollis id. Sed dapibus elit ut neque rutrum dignissim. Nulla eros nisl, venenatis quis rhoncus sit amet, molestie nec nisl. Pellentesque vel neque sapien, et sagittis nulla.</p>

<p>Aliquam eu iaculis mauris. Etiam arcu lectus, imperdiet sit amet volutpat vitae, commodo sed nibh. Fusce faucibus tempor cursus. Donec ut ligula tortor. Maecenas malesuada, diam vitae pharetra dictum, erat ante iaculis risus, sed sollicitudin nisl nisl vel metus. Nulla libero augue, convallis nec luctus id, iaculis nec urna. Cras vitae mi ut augue ultricies tempus.</p>

<p>Vestibulum euismod vehicula sollicitudin. Duis nibh justo, rhoncus ac ullamcorper nec, rutrum sit amet leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum varius posuere nisi sed aliquet. Etiam dolor nisi, placerat vel congue tempus, posuere sed erat. Phasellus turpis eros, molestie sed consequat in, pretium at erat. In sed faucibus metus. Vestibulum fermentum libero nec eros fermentum dapibus. Duis nec libero eros. Pellentesque magna ligula, sagittis dictum fringilla at, posuere porttitor sem. Donec aliquam, ipsum quis pulvinar dapibus, augue sem viverra sapien, nec tempus odio nulla ac metus. Nunc ut augue mi, nec consequat urna.</p>
    
    
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent bibendum, lorem vel tincidunt imperdiet, nibh elit laoreet felis, a bibendum nisl tortor non orci. Donec pretium fermentum felis, quis aliquet est rutrum ut. Integer quis massa ut lacus viverra pharetra in eu lacus. Aliquam tempus odio adipiscing diam pellentesque rhoncus. Curabitur a bibendum est. Mauris vehicula cursus risus id luctus. Curabitur accumsan venenatis nibh, non egestas ipsum vulputate ac. Vivamus consectetur dolor sit amet enim aliquet eu scelerisque ipsum hendrerit. Donec lobortis suscipit vestibulum. Nullam luctus pellentesque risus in ullamcorper. Nam neque nunc, mattfdis vitae ornare ut, feugiat a eratd. Ut tempus diaculis augue vel pellentesque.</p>

<p>Vestibulum nunc massa, gravida quis porta nec, feugiat id metus. Nunc ac arcu dolor, quis vestibulum leo. Cras viverra mollis ipsum, non rhoncus lectus aliquam et. Morbi faucibus purus sit amet lacus aliquet elementum. Donec sit amet posuere enim. Cras in eros id tortor fringilla ultricies. Mauris faucibus ullamcorper velit, pulvinar varius odio eleifend eu. Quisque id odio metus. Morbi adipiscing ultricies posuere. Pellentesque elementum porttitor eros in molestie. Maecenas ut leo quis nisi tempor tincidunt.</p>

<p>Donec nunc ligula, vulputate quis mollis eu, interdum quis libero. Donec nulla ante, facilisis sit amet vulputate at, tincidunt a velit. Maecenas vestibulum, nulla sed tincidunt viverra, lorem turpis aliquam urna, ut pretium orci purus consequat augue. Etiam a enim orci, vitae pulvinar odio. In elit urna, tincidunt a pellentesque et, scelerisque at nibh. Sed nec est sapien. Aliquam ullamcorper eros eu quam ultrices vel faucibus eros interdum. Etiam mattis eleifend sapien, eu iaculis massa feugiat sed. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus facilisis ultricies eros, a pretium purus mollis id. Sed dapibus elit ut neque rutrum dignissim. Nulla eros nisl, venenatis quis rhoncus sit amet, molestie nec nisl. Pellentesque vel neque sapien, et sagittis nulla.</p>

<p>Aliquam eu iaculis mauris. Etiam arcu lectus, imperdiet sit amet volutpat vitae, commodo sed nibh. Fusce faucibus tempor cursus. Donec ut ligula tortor. Maecenas malesuada, diam vitae pharetra dictum, erat ante iaculis risus, sed sollicitudin nisl nisl vel metus. Nulla libero augue, convallis nec luctus id, iaculis nec urna. Cras vitae mi ut augue ultricies tempus.</p>

<p>Vestibulum euismod vehicula sollicitudin. Duis nibh justo, rhoncus ac ullamcorper nec, rutrum sit amet leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum varius posuere nisi sed aliquet. Etiam dolor nisi, placerat vel congue tempus, posuere sed erat. Phasellus turpis eros, molestie sed consequat in, pretium at erat. In sed faucibus metus. Vestibulum fermentum libero nec eros fermentum dapibus. Duis nec libero eros. Pellentesque magna ligula, sagittis dictum fringilla at, posuere porttitor sem. Donec aliquam, ipsum quis pulvinar dapibus, augue sem viverra sapien, nec tempus odio nulla ac metus. Nunc ut augue mi, nec consequat urna.</p>
  </div>
    </div>
```

(perfectibly I grant you) but I have a problem, I want to put before and after the div .container?fullscreen2 other div that would not be affected by the mask (as on the example site kozowood)
can you help me please?

Many thanks

Comment: the website used as reference doesn't work from desktop but only from mobile. The action to see the animation isn't clear and I couldn't find it. The goal you are aiming to isn't clear either: _I want to put before and after the div .container?fullscreen2 other div that would not be affected by the mask_ -doesn't translate to anything meaningful. Can you please rephrase it to make it more clear?

Comment: Hello Diego, 
the kozowood-dot-com/en site is visible on desktop 
then if in my code you want to put a
<div>before</div>
<div class="container fullscreen2">
  <div class="content">......</div>
</div>
<div>after</div>
they are affected by the mask. 
I only want the mask on the .containerfullscreen2 div.

Answer (score 0):

The struggle you are having isolating the mask to the intended container is because of `position: fixed` set on the masking element.

A different approach could be having a pseudo element set via css rule, with a `radial-gradient` background masking its parent like this:

```
.content::before {
    /* ... */
    background: radial-gradient(
      circle at center,
      transparent 10%,
      red calc(10% + 1px)
    );
    /* ... */
}
```

There we have a circle at the center with a radius length 10% (of the total width) showing the underlying content (transparent) and the remaining space as red.

The following demo shows a complete scenario with a `.before` and `.after` divs sibling of `.content`. You can control the radius of the circle mask by moving the slider below that will range between 0 and 100%.

There's a js code handling the `input` event of the range slider, that will set the `--radius` css variable of the element so that the css rule will apply the `radial-gradient` depending on that value.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  
  const animateBtn = document.getElementById('animate');
  const rangeInput = document.getElementById('radius-slider');
  const box = document.getElementById('masked-content');  

  //when the range slider has its value changed
  rangeInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
    //sets the mask radius with the corresponding value
    setMaskRadius(this.value);
    updateButtonState(this.value);
  });

  //function to set the --radius css variable for the box style
  const setMaskRadius = (perc)=>{
    const radiusValue = perc + '%';
    box.style.setProperty('--radius', radiusValue);
  }
  
  //function to update the button status depending on perc (animate/reset)
  const updateButtonState = (perc)=>{
    if(perc == 100){
      animateBtn.dataset.currentStateIsOver = 'true';
      animateBtn.textContent = animateBtn.dataset.resetStateLabel;
    }else{
      animateBtn.dataset.currentStateIsOver = 'false';
      animateBtn.textContent = animateBtn.dataset.animateStateLabel;
    }      
  }  
  
  //on animate button click
  document.querySelector('button')
    .addEventListener('click', ()=>{          
      
      //if the button is intended to reset the slider instead of animating
      if (animateBtn.dataset.currentStateIsOver == 'true'){        
        rangeInput.value = 0;
        rangeInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));      
        return;
      }
      
      //disable the animate button      
      animateBtn.disabled = true;

      //increment the range slider control value by 1 every 10ms
      var timer = setInterval(()=>{
        const currentValue = parseInt(rangeInput.value);          
        rangeInput.value = currentValue + 1;
        rangeInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
        //when the value is 100, stop the timer
        if (currentValue == 99){          
          clearInterval(timer);          
          animateBtn.disabled = false;
        }
      }, 10);      
    });
    
  updateButtonState(0);
});
```

```css
:root {
  --radius: 0%;  
}

.before,
.after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: .5em 0;
}

.content {
  position: relative;  
  overflow: hidden;
  border: dashed 4px gray;
  padding: .5em;
}

#radius-slider {
  margin-top: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button{
  width: 100%;  
  height: 3em;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content::before {
  --mask-color: red;
  
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  background: radial-gradient(
    circle at center,
    transparent var(--radius),
    var(--mask-color) calc(var(--radius) + 1px)
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="before">BEFORE .content</div>

<div id="masked-content" class="content">
  <p>Vestibulum nunc massa, gravida quis porta nec, feugiat id metus. Nunc ac arcu odolor, quis vestibulum leo. Cras viverra mollis ipsum, non rhoncus lectus aliquam et. Morbi faucibus purus sit amet lacus aliquet elementum. Donec sit amet posuere enim.</p>
  
  <p>Vestibulum nunc massa, gravida quis porta nec, feugiat id metus. Nunc ac arcu odolor, quis vestibulum leo. Cras viverra mollis ipsum, non rhoncus lectus aliquam et. Morbi faucibus purus sit amet lacus aliquet elementum. Donec sit amet posuere enim.</p>
      
  <p>Vestibulum nunc massa, gravida quis porta nec, feugiat id metus. Nunc ac arcu odolor, quis vestibulum leo. Cras viverra mollis ipsum, non rhoncus lectus aliquam et. Morbi faucibus purus sit amet lacus aliquet elementum. Donec sit amet posuere enim.</p>
</div>

<div class="after">AFTER .content</div>

<button
  id="animate"
  data-current-state-is-over="false"
  data-animate-state-label="Animate to 100%"
  data-reset-state-label="Reset to 0%"></button>

<input type="range" id="radius-slider" min="0" max="100" value="0">
```